# How to optimize this function?

Tags: optimization

There's a simple code and I'm trying to optimize it.

Please share your though if you have any ideas.

```
struct Participant {
    uint256 balance;
    uint256[] previousBalances;
}
mapping(address => Participant) private participants;

function deposit() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "invalid");
    participants[msg.sender].previousBalances.push(participants[msg.sender].balance);
    participants[msg.sender].balance += msg.value;
}
```

I have a minor solution, but its effect is not much.

```
struct Participant {
    uint256 balance;
    uint256[] previousBalances;
}
mapping(address => Participant) private participants;

function deposit() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "invalid");
    Participant storage participant = participants[msg.sender];
    participant.previousBalances.push(participant.balance);
    participant.balance += msg.value;
}
```

Original cost: **68312** gas

Optimized cost: **68147** gas -> saved **165** gas only

Comment: Do you need the previousBalances to be on chain? If not, you could emit the previousBalance as an event and keep track of those of chain. That would save some gas

Comment: The goal is to keep the logic of this contract and optimize the gas usage.